# RStudio on mac unable to locate pdflatex (within its global environment variables folder) for converting .Rmd into .pdf

Tags: installing, mac, mactex, rstudio

I want to convert `.Rmd` files to `.pdf` in RStudio 3.3.2 on a Mac OS Sierra.
`RStudio` requires packages from the LaTeX distribution for the same viz., pdflatex.
I believe `BasicTeX` (220 Mb) is a lighter version of the TeX distribution (2.7GB)

However, even after installing BasicTeX RStudio says pdflatex not found.
I have checked both in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/bin` ,and they don't seem to have 'pdflatex`

Q1.**The documentation of BasicTeX suggests that it includes** `pdftex.` **Is that the same or does it contain** `pdflatex`?

Q2.**What is the best way to include/install the** `pdflatex` **file in the** `basicTeX` **directory?**

Couldn't find something on the same lines here or www in general, any help on this is truly appreciated!

Best,

S

**EDIT:** It turned out that the BasicTeX package includes pdflatex and the glitch was the location of the global environment variables in RStudio.

Comment: BasicTeX does have pdflatex so something else is wrong. In Terminal.app what does `echo $PATH` return? You might have to add /Library/TeX/texbin somewhere in RStudio Preferences; I'm not familiar with RStudio.

Comment: `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin` Not sure if that helped, thanks for your response though!

Comment: can you `cd /Library/TeX/texbin` and then `pwd -P` and report the result? and also what does `which pdflatex` and `which -a pdflatex` say?

Comment: So, when I do `cd /Library/TeX/texbin` and then `pwd -P` I get `/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/bin/x86_64-darwin`

Comment: And, when I do `which pdflatex` and `which -a pdflatex` I get the same result i.e. `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`

Comment: Since RStudio engine is known to mess up paths, I am trying to copy the file "pdflatex" from `/Library/TeX/texbin` to `/usr/bin` with a sudo `cp ~/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex ~/usr/bin/pdflatex` but strangely it says "_no such file or directory_"                                                   
**Any clue what's going on?**       I mean I see pdflatex in `/TeX/texbin` when I do `ls -a`                                                                      
Again, thanks for responding @jfbu .

Comment: Copying things will only make things worse.  RStudio should not have a problem with BasicTeX, (confirmed) so there's something else going on.  Is your RStudio and `knitr` R package up-to-date?

Comment: Is the error you're getting generated by `pandoc`?  This may be the same problem reported here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207813468-pdflatex-not-found-only-for-button

Comment: @AlanMunn I believe I have the latest versions of RStudio as well as knitr .                                                                        `Sys.getenv("PATH")` in RStudio returns                                                         
 `[1] "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"` but pdflatex is not there in that folder. Which is why I was copying it.

Comment: My problem is similar to the one described here: (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201410073-pdflatex-error-on-OSX)  so,`system("pandoc -s 01-myanalysis.html -o 01-myanalysis.pdf")` returns
`pandoc: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.` **Any clue what else could be the problem?** Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well the path is definitely wrong. `Sys.getenv("PATH")` includes `/Library/TeX/texbin` for me.  Did you try restarting RStudio?

Comment: Also, try logging out of your account and back in.

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting RStudio. Unfortunately, the env var path has NOT changed. Same problem described here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200657486-RStudio-system-path

Comment: Is there a way to modify the "PATH"? Couldn't find much info online.

Comment: Does `/etc/paths.d` contain the file `TeX`?

Comment: @SachinD : ok, you've confirmed that pdflatex is there. However, copying pdflatex to another location won't work since it won't be able to find packages it needs to compile your file. Please report a bug to the RStudio folks and try to find out what has to be changed there to get it to have a correct internal path.

Comment: @HerbSchulz The problem is not directly an RStudio bug, since the path is read correctly for me.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, `/etc/paths.d` contains `TeX`

Comment: **Got it!** Used the `Sys.setenv()` with arguments (/from/current/folder/path,  /to/new/folder/path) to redirect the environment variables' path to `/usr/texbin` and now RStudio and Pandoc are able to access TeX files.                                
@HerbSchulz @HeikoOberdiek  @AlanMunn @jfbu  Thanks all for your time!

Comment: I'm glad you've got something working, but `/usr/texbin` shouldn't exist in Sierra.

Comment: @SachinD : what version of the operating system are you using? You should've using \Library/TeX/texbin rather than /usr/texbin for all recent OS versions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has been resolved and the question now includes an edit indicating that the problem was not the one for which a solution was requested.

Comment: @cfr Sure. And, thanks for updating the tags to "installing", "mactex" along with "rstudio"!

Comment: It wasn't off-topic, of course. We just have limited choice of reasons for closure and off-topic at least let's me write an appropriate close reason in!